# How to set Character Limit with PHP GD Image Library

Tags: php

I am creating a Dynamic Image with PHP GD Image Library. Everything is complete with just this. I want to know that how may I limit Character like 45 character will only show and if the character is more than 45 then it will show something else.

Can anyone please write a example of code for this?

Answer (score 0):

use [`strlen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) as such

```
if(strlen($str) > 45){
    $str = substr($str, 0, 45) . "…";#change to what you want
}
```